# Локализация приложения для AppStore

Tags: строки, swift, файлы, locale, локализация

Такой вопрос. 
Если язык  разработки приложения английский и он (Base) + локализация на русский. Нужно создавать такой же стринговый файл локализации для английского ?

Comment: [Ссылка на официальную документацию](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нужен только один файл Localizable.strings с содержимым примерно таким:

```
...
"Hello!" = "Привет!";
...
```

если Вы об этом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А то я делал бы много лишней работы .